# Printing mutiple columns in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and the Pandas module, but I can't seem to get this to work.

This is my code. I'm using a csv file containing the month and rainfall for Singapore.

Below is my code: 0

```
df = pd.read_csv('rainfall-monthly-total.csv')

print ((df['total_rainfall'])[df.total_rainfall == df['total_rainfall'].max()])
print ((df['month'])[df.total_rainfall == df['total_rainfall'].max()])
print ((df['total_rainfall', 'month'])[df.total_rainfall == df['total_rainfall'].max()])
```

The first two statements work fine. But something is wrong with the third and I can't find out why. Below is the output.

```
"/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/bin/python" "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/Panda Tutorial.py"
299    765.9
Name: total_rainfall, dtype: float64
299    2006-12
Name: month, dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: ('total_rainfall', 'month')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/Panda Tutorial.py", line 16, in <module>
    print ((df['total_rainfall', 'month'])[df.total_rainfall == df['total_rainfall'].max()])
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Phyton for Finance/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: ('total_rainfall', 'month')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using PyCharm with python 3.7.
How do I get python to print out both columns for that particular month?

Comment: Please post code snippets not code snapshots.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it's more convenient now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
print ((df[['total_rainfall', 'month']])[df.total_rainfall == df['total_rainfall'].max()]
```

You need to convert single square brackets to double:

```
['total_rainfall', 'month']
```

TO

```
[['total_rainfall', 'month']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. You need to use use a list of columns you want to print. so use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter your data frame with conditions:

```
print(df.loc[df.total_rainfall == df['total_rainfall'].max(), ['total_rainfall', 'month']])
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't print out the month with the maximum rainfall, which is what I wanted. My above code is similar, but it runs into error.